# Zenity with iPython?

Tags: python, shell, ipython, zenity

Is there anything like Zenity built into iPython?

If not, what would be the best way to approach creating Zenity-like shell scripts with iPython?

Or should I just use regular Python and make a small GUI application (e.g., with PyQt)?

I'm trying to keep it really simple and convert an existing bash shell script into something Python-based (as a learning exercise).

I'm running Linux (and I don't need to be concerned with other platforms).

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of IPython here, can you clarify why it would be IPython-specific, rather than just Python?

Comment: Some of the iPython clients/consoles are really nice (notebooks and QtConsole). If those extended features had something that would meet my needs, I would just use that (even if it wasn't part of Python).

Comment: Ah, okay.  Then the answer to your question is No, IPython does not provide any such tools.

Comment: @minrk - good point. But I suppose I could change my approach a little and use an iPython notebook instead of a Zenity-like toolkit. (I haven't experimented with notebooks much yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, and It's called [PyZenity](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyZenity). 
Additional Info Available [Here.](http://code.google.com/p/pyzenity/)

Comment: that project needs a download -- or it needs to be hosted at github ;) (I don't use svn anymore)